# Get average from multiple JSON objects values

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

I have data the following data:

```
var v = {
  "2015-09-23":[
    {"AllConversions":"0.1","AverageCpc":"0.01","AverageCpm":"0.02","AveragePosition":"8.3",Id:1},
    {"AllConversions":"0.0","AverageCpc":"0.00","AverageCpm":"0.00","AveragePosition":"9.0",Id:1}
  ],
  "2015-09-18":[
    {"AllConversions":"0.1","AverageCpc":"77.14","AverageCpm":"239.57","AveragePosition":"7.7",Id:1},
    {"AllConversions":"0.0","AverageCpc":"39.97","AverageCpm":"703.91","AveragePosition":"3.8",Id:1},   
    {"AllConversions":"0.0","AverageCpc":"20.40","AverageCpm":"381.36","AveragePosition":"4.3",Id:1}
  ]
};

var columns = [
    "AllConversions",
  "AverageCpc",
  "AverageCpm",
  "AveragePosition"
];
```

And I want to return the following object which is the sum of all the fields without Id:

```
{
  "2015-09-23": [
        {"AllConversions":"0.1","AverageCpc":"0.01","AverageCpm":"0.02","AveragePosition":"17.3",Id:1}
  ],
    "2015-09-18": [
        {"AllConversions":"0.1","AverageCpc":"137.51","AverageCpm":"1324.84","AveragePosition":"15.8",Id:1}
  ]
}
```

I tried this code utilising underscrore:

```
_.each(columns,function(item){
    var out = _(groups).map(function (g, key) {
        return {
            Date: key,
                item: _(g).reduce(function (m, x) { return m + x.item; }, 0)
        }
    });
});
```

But I get a 'NaN' error when running the code.

Comment: Please format your code properly

Comment: I would sum all objects on server-side and return it in JSON. In case you have access to server-side.

Comment: Just iterate through the Json array values!! and store them in a array and find the average

Comment: server side not possible for me the data coming from GoogleAdwordApi we are accessing data and changing  in js only @ Aleksej Vasinov

Comment: @mitrap check my answer and mark it as correct and vote it up if it helps..

Comment: What is `groups` in your second line of the underscore code here: `_(groups).map(function (g, key)` ???

Comment: I am trying it is using for grouping the fields based on key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out..

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var v={

        "2015-09-23":[
            {"AllConversions":"0.1","AverageCpc":"0.01","AverageCpm":"0.02","AveragePosition":"8.3",Id:1},    
            {"AllConversions":"0.0","AverageCpc":"0.00","AverageCpm":"0.00","AveragePosition":"9.0",Id:1}
        ],

        "2015-09-18":[
            {"AllConversions":"0.1","AverageCpc":"77.14","AverageCpm":"239.57","AveragePosition":"7.7",Id:1},
            {"AllConversions":"0.0","AverageCpc":"39.97","AverageCpm":"703.91","AveragePosition":"3.8",Id:1},   

            {"AllConversions":"0.0","AverageCpc":"20.40","AverageCpm":"381.36","AveragePosition":"4.3",Id:1}

        ]};


        var columns=[
        "AllConversions","AverageCpc","AverageCpm","AveragePosition"
        ];

    var output = {};
    var smallOutput = {};
    var tempDate = [];
        for(var i in v){
            var temp = 0;
            for(var j = 0; j < columns.length ; j++){
                for(var k = 0 ; k < v[i].length; k++)   temp += parseFloat(v[i][k][columns[j]]);

                smallOutput[columns[j]] = temp ;
                temp=0;

            }
            output[[i]] = smallOutput;
        }

        console.log(output);


</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the fiddle.. https://jsfiddle.net/4t1teyk0/

Check your console.

Here is the output

[image]